# Wanting to scan a row and return all matched values from the top column to form a list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

My spreadsheet is like this

| Hour | Orders | Name1 | Name2 | Name3 | Name4 | Name5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7-8 | 27 | Pick | Load | Pick | Load | Runner |
| 8-9 | 19 | Pick | Load | Pick | Load | Runner |
| 9-10 | 21 | Pick | Load | Load | Pick | Load |
| 10-11 | 32 | Pick | Load | Load | Pick | Load |

Let's say for 10-11 I want to scan that row or index it then return all the names of who is loading for that hour.
So, in a new column I'd have 10-11 with a list of names under it for who is loading.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! What about `{=A5&":"&TEXTJOIN(",";1;IF(C5:G5="Load";$C$1:$G$1;""))}`? (It's an [ARRAY formula](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7), confirm it with Ctrl+Shift+Enter)

Comment: I get a problem with this formula error, and it highlights the 2nd " in "," after TEXTJOIN(.  It says TEXTJOIN(delimiter, ignore_empty,text1,...)

Comment: Sorry, this will work in LibreOffice Calc or Google Sheets as `=ArrayFormula(TRIM(A5)&":"&TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF(C5:G5="Load",$C$1:$G$1,"")))` with result **10-11:Name2,Name3,Name5**  . I don’t know why your Excel is acting up... By the way, what version are you using?

Comment: This seems closer as it highlights all the right thing but I get #NAME? in the cell and the warning says this contains unrecognized txt.  Microsoft Pro Plus 2019, Version 1808 Build 10402.20023

Comment: *contains unrecognized txt* Please rewrite the formula by hand, paying special attention to double quotes and operand delimiters. It seems that one or more double quotes in your formula have changed to typographical quotes (**”** instead of **"** - it is sometimes very difficult to see the difference), and Excel doesn't understand what it's about. It is also possible that your Excel expects a comma instead of a semicolon as parameter separators.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in `A1:G5` and you have the `FILTER` formula you can use:

```
=FILTER(C1:G1,FILTER($C$2:$G$5,$A$2:$A$5=$A$8)=$B$8)
```

Where `A8` is the hour you're after and `B8` is the type you're after.

[image]

Wrap with `TRANSPOSE` to have the list in a column.
[image]

**Edit:  Non-365 version.**
Both these formula will no doubt need to be entered as array formula.
This formula will return the names, but will have blank cells where there is not a match.

```
=TRANSPOSE(IF(INDEX($C$2:$C$5,MATCH($A$8,$A$2:$A$5,0)):INDEX($G$2:$G$5,MATCH($A$8,$A$2:$A$5,0))=$A$9,$C$1:$G$1,""))
```

This formula will remove the blank cells.  Note the -9 in the formula is because the data is on row 10.

```
=IF(ISERROR(SMALL(IF(A10:A14<>"",ROW(A10:A14)-9),ROW(A10:A14)-9)),"",INDEX(A10:A14,MATCH(SMALL(IF(A10:A14<>"",ROW(A10:A14)-9),ROW(A10:A14)-9),IF(A10:A14<>"",ROW(A10:A14)-9),0)))
```

[Removing Blanks](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/formulas/array-formulas-removing-blanks.htm)

[image]

Comment: That function isn't valid.   Would a VLOOKUP and match or a getpivotdata work?

Comment: Have added formula that don't use `FILTER`.